# need some modification on my slideshow code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i insert the previous and next image over the image? i could not add it over the image. My css is like this:

```
#prev a {
    background:url('../images/left.png');
    width:30px;
    height:102px;
    position:absolute;
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 0 0 40px;
}

#next a {
    background:url('../images/right.png');
    width:30px;
    height:102px;
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 0 0 70px;
}

#next a:hover {
    background:url('../images/right_over.png');
}

#prev a:hover {
    background:url('../images/left_over.png');
}
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle account so we can see the html code and everything in action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficulty to say what is the problem without an example code but maybe the #next and #previous is just overlapped under the slider image. Try to add some very big z-index to them. Something like this:

```
#prev a {
    background:url('../images/left.png');
    width:30px;
    height:102px;
    position:absolute;
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 0 0 40px;

    z-index: 99999999;
}

#next a {
    background:url('../images/right.png');
    width:30px;
    height:102px;
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 0 0 70px;

    z-index: 99999999;
}
```